# Force bootstrap row to take up remaining page height and not expand past screen height

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Angular application that utilises bootstrap to create the below (simplified structure).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header>
        <div class="mat-card> 
             <!-- Header stuff -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="mat-card> 
                <!-- Table goes here -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4>
            <div class="mat-card> 
                <!-- Other stuff --> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `col-8` column that is present within the structure is going to contain mat-card which will contain a table that will have a variable number of rows. This means that if the table contains a high number of rows the table may be too big for the page and will possible spill out off the screen, forcing the user to scroll to view the entire table.

I want to be able to force the `col-8` column to only use the space required to display the table and no more, however I want the column to expand with the column. So a table of 5 rows will cause `col-8` to use less space than a table of 10 rows.

However, I also want to be able to force a maximum height onto the col-8 so that the column will only become as tall as the remaining vertical space on the page, the maximum height of the col-8 therefore should be the `browser window - the height of the header`

So, to summarise.

1. `col-8` contains table of varying height
2. `col-8` height should expand to accomodate height of table
3. `col-8` height should not expand past the height of the browser window

I can do exactly what I want to do by setting the column to `height: vh` and `overflow-y: scroll`, however this means the column will be a fixed height and won't be responsive, so although it's close it's not the full solution.

Answer (score 0):

But with `max-height` instead of `height`, it will be responsive imo. Right?

Comment: The issue is getting it to calculate max-height of the page. Since the header bar and the rows are two separate Angular components.

Comment: If the header is e.g. 20vh, you can set your array to max-height: 80vh isn't it ?

Comment: Not as simple as that unfortunately. The header is a shared component and can't be altered

Comment: Do you know the size of this header? It is not a question of altering its size but of adapting the size of the array according to the size of the header. For example with calc